# Connection timed out (trying to connect via tcp://db1.domain.com:3306)

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php

I'm getting intermittent errors in my Apache error_log like this:

```
sql[10315]: mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: Connection timed out - /page.html -
sql[10315]: Failed to connect to db:  - /page.html -
sql[9191]: mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: [2002] Connection timed out (trying to connect via tcp://db1.domain.com:3306) - /page.html
```

I can ping db1.domain.com (which is defined in my /etc/hosts file), I can telnet to db1.domain.com on port 3306. I can even use the cli mysql client using "mysql -h db1.domain.com -p"

There are no rules in iptables and I can't see any packets being dropped on the NIC on ifconfig. There are no firewalls between this server and the database server.

This is 1 of 6 webservers we use to serve our website, the other 5 are not showing the same errors.

Is there anywhere else I can check for problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up restarting the server which fixed the problem. I thinking it's probably a hardware fault with our backlink network. If it happens again I'll try and narrow it down by disabling network interfaces and bringing them back up.